# How to add hintText on Search Delegate?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How to change hint text and hint text color on Flutter showSearch()

```
 AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: appBarIcon(context),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(
                    context: context,
                    delegate: CustomSearchDelegateAssets(_searchdata, widget.regId));
              })
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the sources](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7a4c33425d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/search.dart#L51) of `showSearch` method, it simply pushes a new route - [`_SearchPageRoute`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7a4c33425d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/search.dart#L267).

This internally defined route provides a stateful widget (`_SearchPage`), which consists of a newly built `AppBar` with a textfield in it.

What you need to do is create a custom route based on `_SearchPageRoute`, returning custom `_SearchPage`. The route needs to be pushed through your own method based on `showSearch` logic.

To achieve custom `hintText` & `hintStyle` - modify `InputDecoration` in your custom `_SearchPageState`.

---

e.g. `MySearchPageRoute`

```dart
class MySearchPageRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  // ...
  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return MySearchPage<T>( // KEY PROP: Custom stateful widget based on `_SearchPage`
      delegate: delegate,
      animation: animation,
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```

MySearchPage:

```dart
class MySearchPage<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  // ...
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MySearchPageState<T>();
}
class MySearchPageState<T> extends State<MySearchPage<T>> {
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
    return Semantics(
      // ...
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // ...
          title: TextField(
            // ...
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "My Custom Search Label", // KEY PROP
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // KEY PROP
            ),
          ),
          // ...
        ),
        // ...
      )
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```

Push the route:

```dart
Future<T> showMySearch<T>({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required SearchDelegate<T> delegate,
  String query = '',
}) {
  // ...
  return Navigator.of(context).push(MySearchPageRoute<T>( // KEY PROP
    delegate: delegate,
  ));
}
```

---

In other words - simply copy over `_SearchPageRoute`, `_SearchPage`, `_SearchPageState` and `showSearch` [from the sources](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7a4c33425d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/search.dart). Then make the changes in the lines that I marked with `// KEY PROP`.